# Laravel - view não funciona

Tags: laravel

Estou com problemas: estou editando um site e a view do Laravel só esta funcionando no `/` e quando coloco outro tipo `http://localhost/blog/public/Termos` ela dá como não tivesse encontrado 
codig rotas:

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
Route::get('/Contato', 'SiteController@Contrat');
Route::get('/Dicas', 'SiteController@Dicas');
Route::get('/Regulamento', 'SiteController@Regulamento');
Route::get('/Termos', 'SiteController@Termos');
Route::get('/Tutorial', 'SiteController@Tutorial');
Route::get('/Cadastro', 'SiteController@Cadastro');
```

codigo SiteController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('/site.Home.index') ;
    }
    public function Contrato(){
        return view('/site.Contrato.index') ;
    }
    public function Dicas(){
        return view('/site.Dicas.index') ;
    }
    public function Regulamento(){
        return view('/site.Regulamento.index') ;
    }
    public function Termos(){
        return view('/site.Termos.index') ;
    }
    public function Tutorial(){
        return view('/site.Tutorial.index') ;
    }
    public function Cadastro(){
        return view('/site.Cadastro.index') ;
    }
}
```

Print do erro q fala paginanot
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem o artigo existe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O estranho e que se eu trocar o local do:

```
public function index(){
            return view('/site.Home.index') ;
        }
```

Por:

```
public function index(){
            return view('/site.Termos.index') ;
        }
```

ele acha a pagina
e se eu fazer o mesmo procedimento na `Route::get` e trocar o comando `Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');` por `Route::get('/', 'SiteController@Termos');` ai ele acha normalmente o estranho q so quer funcionar o /

Comment: Habilite o Debug no seu `.env` assim fica mais fácil saber onde está o erro.

Comment: se for o `APP_DEBUG` ele ja esta `true`

Comment: Não vi configurada a rota `public/Termos` no seu arquivo de rotas e tente tirar a barra na ` `return view('/site.Termos.index') ;` deixando apenas `return view('site.Termos.index') ;`

Comment: Tente acessar então com `http://localhost/blog/Termos`

Comment: @adventistaam tirei e continua n encontrando

Comment: @adventistaam se tentar acessar igual vc falou ele da objeto n encontrado

Comment: Tire a barra la de dentro do arquivo `index.blade.php` da pasta `Termos` na linha extends também

Comment: @adventistaam sim tirei deixei igual vc falou e ele continua n encontrando,e igual informado na minha ultima atualização caso eu troque de lugar ele acha, ele so esta achando a pastra / o resto ele n esta achando

Comment: Você tirou a barra tanto do controller quanto da view arquivo blade?

Comment: sim, fiz igual vc me informou

Comment: Tem como mostrar o que o debug exibe?

Comment: o que tem em `templede1`?

Comment: @adventistaam n estou conseguindo dar o DebugBar ele n esta retornando nada e no tmplede1 so tem o corpo do html e  @yield('body')

Comment: você tem o codigo no gitHub ?

Comment: Oque notei e que ele n esta nem entrando na `public function Termos(){ }` pois caso eu coloque o mesmo return view `'/site.Termos.index'` na `public function Index(){ }` ele achao arquivo e mostra normalmente

Comment: tente colocar apenas um `echo 'Pagina termos';` na função Termos e tente acessar

Comment: igual informei no comentario acima ele n quer achar a function termos ele so esta achando a function principal

Comment: Estou instalando aqui pra fazer esse teste

Comment: mano mo estranho pq igual informei se eu trocar a return view da Function index() pelo return view da Function Termos ele acha a pagina

Comment: e se eu fazer o mesmo procedimento na `Route::get` e trocar o comando `Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');` por `Route::get('/', 'SiteController@Termos');` ai ele acha normalmente o estranho q so quer funcionar o /

Comment: Você já acessou o arquivo .htaccess na pasta public e colocou a linha `RewriteBase /blog` abaixo de `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: Porque do jeito que lhe falei aqui no meu funcionou

Comment: @adventistaam coloquei oq vc falou RewriteBase /blog e agora so da objeto n encontrado

Comment: Verifica se essa linha no arquivo httpd.conf do apache está descomentada: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: reiniciei a maquina aqui e derrepende funcionou normalmente q loco

Comment: Obrigado @adventistaam pela atenção q vc me deu

Comment: Tamu junto! Que bom que funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, tente parar o `php artisan serve` e depois o inicie novamente.
E inicie novamente. Já tive problemas e era o cache, quando eu criava novas rotas com o serve ativo.
Caso não dê certo, limpe os caches de configuração com :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Ah, dica extra. Preste atenção na sua outra rota : `Route::get('/Contato', 'SiteController@Contrat');` Você a está chamando pela url Contato ao invés de Contrato e ao passar para o controller está buscando um método Contrat ao invés de Contrato.

Edit: Vi agora seu comentário que você teve que reiniciar a máquina, então a resposta era cache mesmo. Que bom que funcionou.